# How do I add a va

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a system where every time an input is added into a text box, I can create an array out of my code.

html:

```
<div>
    <p onclick = "addTeamName()"></p>
    <input type = "text" name = "teamName" value = "Team Name" id = "teamname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Team" onclick = "addTeamName()">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function addTeamName() {
   var teamNameValue = document.getElementById("teamname").value;
}
```

I don't know how to make the input a variable and how to make that variable the name a of a two-dimensional array.

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a `<select>`.

Comment: I think a more specific meaningful title may be useful

Answer (score 0):

Considering your scenario a better option would be to store team information as an Object and then keep pushing it in an Array. This will be easy in iteration when you want to access the teams. Referring to same code as yours, some modifications could be done in the 'addTeamName' function.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var teamCounter=1;
    var teamArray=[];
    function addTeamName() {
        var teamDetails = {};
        teamDetails.id = "Team"+teamCounter;
        teamDetails.name = document.getElementById("teamname").value;
        teamArray.push(teamDetails);
        teamCounter++;
        // Array storing list of teams
        console.log(teamArray);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <p onclick = "addTeamName()"></p>
    <input type = "text" name = "teamName" value = "Team Name" id = "teamname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Team" onclick = "addTeamName()">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```